# What webapps are available to monitor my VPS?

Tags: monitoring, vps, performance-monitoring

I would be interested what webapps do you know/use that allows you to monitor VPS. I would like to have the following metrics, CPU, Memory, Disk stats, Apache stats (hits/sec, free agents)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) seems to be the simplest one to install and configure (check your distro repository for packages), you can also try [Nagios](http://nagios.org) as well.

Comment: Munin will log and graph most of the things you are looking for.  It will also to alerts.

Answer (score 0):

With "web app", did you mean you are looking for a free **hosted** server monitoring service?

If you [use a webpage as agent](http://blog.alertfox.com/2011/01/monitoring-disk-space-and-other-status.html) for these internal stats, you can use any of the well-known  website monitoring services with a free plan (AlertFox, Pingdom,...).